# How to scatterplot between 2 rasters and find correlation?

Tags: gis, geospatial, arcgis, correlation

I have 2 raster images of the same area. One raster represents temperature and the other raster gives NDVI details. I want to correlate between NDVI and Temperature. I tried with ArcGIS using band statistics tool which is giving covariance and correlation coefficient values. Along with the values I want to plot them (Scatter plot i.e., temperature vs NDVI). Can some one please guide me in achieving this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

With `R` you can do things like this:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

layerStats(b, 'pearson')
#$`pearson correlation coefficient`
#            red     green      blue
#red   1.0000000 0.9980961 0.9501633
#green 0.9980961 1.0000000 0.9658011
#blue  0.9501633 0.9658011 1.0000000

#$mean
#     red    green     blue 
#182.2855 185.3509 192.8046 

plot(b[[1]], b[[2]])
pairs(b)
```